# Get List<Schema.SObjectField> from field set

Tags: apex, fieldsets, sobjectfield

I know that the name of the object is `Obje` and the name of the field set for this object if `Fieldse`.

Now I would like to get a `List<Schema.SObjectField>` (i.e. fields from the field set).

Right now I found only this approach:

```
public static List<Schema.FieldSetMember> readFieldSet(String fieldSetName, String ObjectName) {
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = GlobalDescribeMap.get(ObjectName);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DescribeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();

        Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName);

        return fieldSetObj.getFields();
}
```

But here I am getting `List<Schema.FieldSetMember>` instead of `List<Schema.SObjectField>`.

Thank you.

After trying out to apply the answer to my problem I ended up with the following code:

```
public static List<Schema.SObjectField> readFieldSet(String fieldSetName, String objectName) {
        List<Schema.SObjectField> res = new List<Schema.SObjectField>();

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = GlobalDescribeMap.get(objectName);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();
        Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = describeSObjectResultObj.fieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName);
        for (Schema.FieldSetMember f: fieldSetObj.getFields()) {
            res.add(describeSObjectResultObj.fields.getMap().get(fieldSetMember.getFieldPath()).getSObjectField());
        }

        return res;
    }
```

And I am getting an error

> Cannot resolve symbol `getSObjectField`

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<Schema.FieldSetMember>` is just what `Schema.FieldSet.getFields()` gives you. You can call `getFieldPath()` on each field set member to obtain the field's API name, and then convert to a `Schema.SObjectField` via

```
Schema.SObjectType.My_Object__c.fields.getMap().get(fieldSetMember.getFieldPath());
```

So given your existing code, you can do something like

```
Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName);
List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldList = new List<Schema.SObjectField>();

for (Schema.FieldSetMember f: fieldSetObj.getFields()) {
    fieldList.add(res.fields.getMap().get(f.getFieldPath()));
}

return fieldList;
```

This might not be the most efficient way to handle this information, but the best approach will depend on your ultimate use case for the field set details.